# Windows Phone 7.1 SDK Crashes My Virtual

Tags: .net, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, hyper-v

I have a Dell Server, and a Hyper-V virtual machine where I have my VS 2010 ultimate installation.  I added the WP7.1 tools last night, and used it this morning, but the framework was giving me, when running the emulator as an administrator: MFPlat.dll is missing error.  I resolved that from this post and installed windows media foundation platform, and the emulator  worked but gave me a message stating "the video hardware may not support XNA development, but silverlight may work OK.  Do you want to continue?" (rough translation).  I understand since it's a dell server, but I can view

I clicked OK, then shortly thereafter, the VM window disappeared, and HyperV reports the virtual machine lost connectivity.  This is the second time I had this problem with a VM (tried this in the past with version 7.0 tools).  Usually shutting down the machine brings it back, but I can't get past this.

Does windows phone tools support VM's at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone tools do support VMs, but the emulator is actually an virtual instance and so causes untold issues when running inside a wrapper VM.  It is not supported to run the emulator inside a VM because of these issues.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637317(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_VM

Comment: That would make sense then, how would you debug your applications?  Are you aware of any alternatives...

Comment: First choice would be to have an OS installed direct to the tin on a machine to do this on.  Second choice would be real phone hardware, but that would rely on having the phone attached by USB to the host computer - I'm not sure if that is possible in your case, though.

Comment: I got the Emulator running within Parallels on a Mac, albeit very slowly.  Never had any luck under Windows...

Comment: @Damian Interesting about the mac, though I hope they come up with an alternative soon.

Comment: This issue has been logged on user voice, please  vote for it: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2344692-enable-the-emulator-to-run-in-vm-s-virtual-machin

Answer (score 0):

please refer this link http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?mfplat.

Extract mfplat.dll from mfplat.zip. We recommend that you extract mfplat.dll to the installation directory of the program that is requesting mfplat.dll.

If that doesn't work, you will have to extract mfplat.dll to your system directory. By default, this is:

C:\Windows\System (Windows 95/98/Me)

C:\WINNT\System32 (Windows NT/2000)

C:\Windows\System32 (Windows XP, Vista, 7)

If you use a 64-bit version of Windows, you should also place mfplat.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Make sure overwrite any existing files (but make a backup copy of the original file).
Reboot your computer.

If the problem still occurs, try the following:

Open Windows Start menu and select "Run...".
Type CMD and press Enter (or if you use Windows ME, type COMMAND)).
Type regsvr32 mfplat.dll and press Enter.